# Show colors swatches in vertical mode for Woocommerce variable products

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I have a Woocommerce shop with some variable products which have color swatches.

How can I show in vertical form instead of horizontal. I have tried to edit them, but I didn't succeed.

```html
<div class="attribute-swatch" attribute-index="">
    <div class="swatchinput">
        <label selectid="colours-available" class="attribute_colours-available_White wcvaswatchlabel wcvasquare" data-option="White" selectedtext="White" style="background-color:#ffffff; width:32px; height:32px; "></label>
    </div>
    <div class="swatchinput">
        <label selectid="colours-available" class="attribute_colours-available_Anthracite grey ANTRA24 wcvaswatchlabel wcvasquare" data-option="Anthracite grey ANTRA24" selectedtext="Anthracite grey ANTRA24" style="background-color:#3a3b45; width:32px; height:32px; "></label>
    </div>
    <div class="swatchinput">
        <label selectid="colours-available" class="attribute_colours-available_Brown RAL 8017 wcvaswatchlabel wcvasquare" data-option="Brown RAL 8017" selectedtext="Brown RAL 8017" style="background-color:#41221d; width:32px; height:32px; "></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the html code in your question is the generated code for the color swatches, you could try to add following CSS rule in the `styles.css` file of your active theme:

```css
.attribute-swatch .swatchinput {
     display: block !important; 
     float: none !important;
}
```

It should work. But if the generated code for your color swatches is different, it will not work…

Comment: thanks for help its works but little problem there check URL. http://hml.nathandasilva.co.uk/product/infinity-by-hugos/

Comment: @UsmanAli Looking to your link web site, first It seems that the html structure has been also changed in a wrong way and then there are a lot of wrong things in the surround CSS styling. Your overlapping problem is not solved in other screen resolutions. So you should do it in another clean way, starting from a clean logical html structure and with correct CSS styling after. If you like/want you could please upvote this answer, Thanks. Related to the CSS of my answer, only `display: block !important;` is necessary.